# Drupal user registration form

Tags: theming

I just want to do somthing without using module like [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2), so here is my requirement.

=> theme user registration form for e.g. I already have a beautiful user registration form as static html template which use bootstrap classes for css so how can I implement this html template in my drupal registration form..

=> In login form I want to remove tabs LIKE create new account and request new password and enstand of these tab I want to give like just before login button.

let me know if anything not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. theme user registration form**

implement hook_theme:

```
function MYMODULE_theme()
{
  $return = array(
    'my_custom_registration_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'my_custom_registration_form'
    ),
  );

  return $return;
}
```

implement hook_form_alter:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  //dpm($form_id);
  if ('user_register_form' == $form_id) {
    $form['#theme'] = 'my_custom_registration_form';
  }
}
```

create `my_custom_registration_form.tpl.php` file in MYMODULE directory, clear the cache, check if it works;

```
<?php dpm($form) ?>
```

copy html from your static file (just form part), put it into `my_custom_registration_form.tpl.php`, example (this will be different in your case):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class=""><?php print render($form['DESIRED_FIELD']) ?></div>
</div>
...

//render other fields (hidden fields), without them submit won't work
<?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>

// or you can render them manually

// <?php print render($form['form_build_id']) ?>
// <?php print render($form['form_token']) ?>
// <?php print render($form['form_id']) ?>
```

**2. In login form i want to remove tabs LIKE create new account and request new password** - you can do it with CSS, or by removing `$tabs` variable from page template (you can create specific page template just for login page),

**3. enstand of these tab i want to give like just before login button** - 
with hook_form_alter fnction you can add other fields (manage theme) to the form

P>S: `dpm()` - is from Devel module

Comment: Too Cool and Easy, i don't have enough point to like. Thanks for your information. i will be use this soon.

Answer (score 0):

For theming of your form :

1. Impletement `hook_form_alter`
2. Add the classes you want to any of form element like `$form['element_name']['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'your_class');`

To Hide Tabs :

1. You can do this with css.
2. or by creating a `page.tpl.php` for user register page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LoginToboggan module](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) for your requirements.

  `Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.`

Elseif you wants to remove create new account tabs.

Go to admin/config/people/accounts and change " Who can register accounts? " to admin only.